# Generate XML file with document constructor from xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-3.0

I have problem to generate .xml file from xquery.
Here is my code:

```
document {
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF-8" href="C:\Users\User\Desktop\UDBXML-lab\artist.xml"?>,
<ARTISTS>
{
for $a in doc("Artists.xml")//ARTIST
return <ARTIST ID="{$a/@ID}">
{$a/*}
{
for $b in doc("Groups.xml")//GROUP
where $a/@ID = $b/@ID
return $b
}
{
for $b in doc("DJ.xml")//DJ
where $a/@ID = $b/@ID
return $b
}
{
for $b in doc("Singers.xml")//SINGER
where $a/@ID = $b/@ID
return $b
}
</ARTIST>
}
</ARTISTS>
}
```

I get error:

A processing instruction must not be named 'xml' in any combination of upper or lower case.

But I don't know which processing instruction to set to save this query in document.

Comment: Which tool or XQuery processor do you use? The XQuery document constructor does not take any XML declaration nor any file name. Saving/serializing to a file is part of the XQuery processor API or GUI or use of the `put` function or a file module.

Comment: I’m using oxigen XML.

Answer (score 1):

You need to leverage XQuery prolog declarations. Here is how to do it.

`base-uri` declaration specifies a directory for all XML files. The other two declarations will create an XML prolog with desired settings.

> XQuery

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare base-uri 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\UDBXML-lab\';
declare option output:omit-xml-declaration "no";
declare option output:encoding "UTF-8";

<ARTISTS>
{
for $a in doc("Artists.xml")//ARTIST
return <ARTIST ID="{$a/@ID}">
{$a/*}
{
for $b in doc("Groups.xml")//GROUP
where $a/@ID = $b/@ID
return $b
}
{
for $b in doc("DJ.xml")//DJ
where $a/@ID = $b/@ID
return $b
}
{
for $b in doc("Singers.xml")//SINGER
where $a/@ID = $b/@ID
return $b
}
</ARTIST>
}
</ARTISTS>
```